# How do i search number in data-validation list?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in v column the data look like 24/25,25/26...up to 100/101 using data validation I put them in a list so now whenever I type 24 in data validation cell it should show me the 24/25 so how do I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can do this simply using Data Validation. You would have to use a ComboBox

Comment: Any other ways do like that i mean using formulas

Comment: Data validation does not have autocomplete